# How to rewrite a derivative w.r.t. tensor as w.r.t. vector

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

I'm stuck on a (probably very simple) problem I've come across.

Take a function $f(A)$ where $A$ is a 2-tensor. Now suppose $A=vv^T$ for an $\mathbb{R}^n$ vector, $v$.

I want to rewrite the object $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$. Using baby math one could come up with something like $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}=v^{-T}\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}$, where $^{-T}$ signifies inverse transpose. But I know this couldn't be correct because $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}$ belongs to a symmetric space whereas the term on right is not.

I'm not sure of the formalism of how to do this. Any help?

Comment: I'm not at all sure, but my instinct is to just use the chain rule like normal to get $\frac {\partial f}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial A}\frac{\partial A}{\partial v}$ which implies that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial A}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial A} =\frac{\partial f}{\partial v}\left(\frac{\partial A}{\partial v}\right)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Using this gives what I have up to factor. I suppose if the chain rule is still a valid approach wrt to non-$\mathbb{R}$ variables, then this answer *must* be symmetric too. Come to think of it, I'm pretty sure $Bv = v^TB$ if $B$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The derivative is 
$$ \eqalign {
 \frac {\partial f} {\partial v} &= 2\,{\rm sym}\bigg(\frac {\partial f} {\partial A}\bigg)\,v \cr
} $$
where ${\rm sym}(X) = {\frac {1} {2}}(X + X^T)$.

To derive it, consider the differential
$$ \eqalign {
 df &= \frac {\partial f} {\partial A} : dA \cr
} $$
where $X:Y = {\rm tr}(X^TY)$ represents the Frobenius product.

Then express $dA$ in terms of $dv$ as 
$$ \eqalign {
  dA &= d(v\,v^T) \cr
  &= dv\,v^T + v\,dv^T \cr
  &= 2\,{\rm sym}(dv\,v^T) \cr
}$$
and substitute into the differential to obtain
$$ \eqalign {
 df &= \frac {\partial f} {\partial A} : 2\,{\rm sym}(dv\,v^T) \cr
    &= 2\,{\rm sym}\bigg(\frac {\partial f} {\partial A}\bigg) : dv\,v^T \cr
    &= 2\,{\rm sym}\bigg(\frac {\partial f} {\partial A}\bigg)\,v : dv \cr
    &= \frac {\partial f} {\partial v} : dv \cr
} $$
This result holds whether $v$ is an $n \times p$ matrix or a vector (i.e. when $p=1$).

Comment: Hello, thank you for this. It is what I had been doing and referred to in the question. Let me enunciate on some of the issues I'm thinking of. I'll write derivatives as $f_{,A}$ etc.

You write $f_{,v}=2\mathrm{sym}(f_{,A}v)$. Although $f_{,A}$ is already symmetric, this looks legit. But let me write the following:

$$
f_{,v}=2f_{,A}v\implies f_{,A}=\frac{1}{2}f_{,v}v^{-1}.
$$

With this second equation, the left hand side is manifestly symmetric whilst the right hand side isn't manifestly so. Will I just need to accept this?

Comment: If $v$ is a vector, what do you mean by $v^{-1}$? For that matter, if $f_{,v}$ is a vector, what do you mean by manifestly symmetric?  What is a symmetric vector?

Comment: I assume $v{-1}$ to be the row vector such that $v^{-1}v=1$. Then $f_{,v}v^{-1}$ should belong to a projection space. $A=vv^T$ is symmetric, which implies $f_{,A}$ is too. This means $f_{,v}v^{-1}$ should be also, but it's not obvious.

Comment: @AlexClose  Take the generic matrix-vector equation $A x = b$.  You're comment implies that you wish to solve for the matrix as $A = b x^{-1}$. But that's not possible.